# How do I disable or hide a survey for my WP users once it has been submitted?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a survey inside a modal. The intent is to display this to logged in users only. That part works fine. The issue is how to prevent it from displaying again once they have submitted it. I'm guessing there are hooks or methods in WP which would make this easy although I am unsure what they would be. Any possible solution would help.

The 2 approaches that first come to mind are a boolean value attached to each user. For example formCompleted = false, then have the posted survey set it to false. The next idea would just be some type of cookie detection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [add a user meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) when he completes the survey:

```
if( user_completed_survey() )
    add_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'survey-done', 1);
```

And check it everytime:

```
if(is_user_logged_in() && !get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'survey-done', true )) {

// show survey

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was mistaken and users don't need to be logged in but this is still awesome info. Based on the actual question I asked though this is the answer.